# Substitute for "gather" function in Matlab

Tags: matlab

The function "gather" in Matlab is available only with the Parallel Computing Toolbox, which I do not have access to. How can I rewrite this line in order not to use the gather function?

```
moveop = @(x) gather(x) ;
```

Answer (score 3):

For data other than `gpuArray`, `distributed`, `codistributed` and (new in R2016b) `tall`, the `gather` function does nothing (however, in R2016b, the no-op version of `gather` ships with MATLAB itself, so you wouldn't have this problem there).

So in this case, you can simply write:

```
moveop = @(x) x;
```